# Link to feedback site in tag filter email does not have the correct formatting

Tags: bug, markdown, hyperlinks, email

I noticed that the email I received for a tag filter I created on [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com) has the following footer:

> Questions? Comments? Let us know on our [feedback site](https://meta.stackexchange.com).

Here's a screenshot of that part as I see it in my inbox:

> [image: Image of email]

Can the formatting of the link to Meta SE over the text "feedback site" be corrected?

Comment: @Shadow Just FYI: to get this on SE's radar, a [tag:status-review] tag needs be added to the question. A bounty brings more attention from regular users, which is helpful when the issue needs more support or input from users, but doesn't bring it to the attention of Stack Overflow staff. Adding the [tag:status-review] tag generates a ticket in SE's task system, which will be triaged into an actual feature request/bug sent to developers. To have a [tag:status-review] tag added to the question, the normal process is to raise an "in need of moderator intervention" flag to request it be added.

Comment: @Makyen The mods here have been quite stringent with adding the tag to such questions. Despite the official guidance that it's only *recommended* and not *required* to ensure that past questions are within the current roadmap to be escalated, I've seen mods enforce this quite hard, even declining one of my flags where the roadmap changed after I'd already cast the flag. I've also seen mods enforce the "positive consensus" requirement quite stringently, to the point where a post I flagged that took months to get a double-digit score was declined as "other posts took 24 hours to get there".

Comment: Granted, most of those flags were back when the flagging criteria were fairly new and mods were still getting settled into the new system, but the "traditional" escalation methods, of ensuring that staff who browse meta come across reports, are still useful today, especially if you request escalation but it gets declined because the mod handling it didn't think it to be useful, especially minor bugs like these.

Comment: @Sonict OK, but a [tag:bug] or [tag:feature-request] question *does nothing useful* (other than letting user's know) until and unless *the company* sees it, so the company knows about it and can choose to take action, or not. The way for the company to see questions on meta sites is to add a [tag:status-review] tag to the question. The bounty makes it more likely that the question is seen *by users*, but not *by the company*. Thus, adding a bounty to something like this question really isn't that valuable/useful, because regular users can't really do much to let the company know about it.