# SE emails contain unparsed Markdown in footer

Tags: bug, email

Today I've noticed this in email message from SE:

[image: footer of SE email, relevant line as text quoted below]

One of lines reads:

```
Questions? Comments? Let us know on our [feedback site](https://meta.stackexchange.com).
```

So yes, I do have a comment about this very line - namely, it contains Markdown instead of intended HTML link.

Comment: Some emails have correct footer, think only the filter emails has it wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Link to feedback site in tag filter email does not have the correct formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354622/link-to-feedback-site-in-tag-filter-email-does-not-have-the-correct-formatting)